# How to force jboss to load classes from jars in webapp's lib

Tags: deployment, jboss, classloading

I am trying to deploy my web application on `jboss-6.0.0Final`, which is currently deployed on `apache tomcat`.
I have two jars one that contains same package which is `org.apache.axis`. I am putting one jar in `<Jboss-home>/server/default/lib` & another jar in `<my-app-war>WEB-INF/lib`.

It is required to put both jars in the class path. No way to remove one of the jar. So I need to keep both jars. & It is giving me following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1828)
```

I think it is due to conflict of same classes in two different jars.

Now, I want to know the way by which I can force jboss to load classes of this particular package from axis.jar exist in /WEB-INF/lib.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to put the JAR in both places?

Comment: Curious to know if you were able to isolate the war.  I'm running into the same issues and isolating doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/solving-jboss-5-classloading-issues


Explode your war, 

In your Exploded WAR web-inf directory add this xml file: jboss-classloading.xml 

 with content:

 (domain is your war name)

```
 <classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
            name="mywar.war"
            domain="mywar_domain"  <!-- (domain is your war name) -->
            parent-domain="Ignored"
            export-all="NON_EMPTY"
            import-all="true">
</classloading>
```

Comment: This is for JBOSS 5 but in JBOSS EAP 6.* + Jboss is using modular dependency so this wont work

Answer (score 0):

I'll share quite simple and straight forward process which I had followed when I came across same situation.

1> Create a **jboss-web.xml** file.

```
  <class-loading java2classloadingcompliance="false">
  <loader-repository>
      com.rts:archive=DTH_PROD.war
      <loader-repository-config>
          java2ParentDelegation=false
      </loader-repository-config>
  </loader-repository>
  </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

**Points:**,

- Begin the xml with  tag which is not visible in the code I'm posting
  Check 3rd line of above code,
- **com.rts** - This is your package name.
- **DTH_PROD.war** - Name of bundle you wish to keep

2> Now place this xml file into WEB-INF directory of your project and voilla!!

Further more you may wish to refer [this article](https://newcircle.com/bookshelf/jboss_admin_tutorial/class_loading) for detailed info. Also comment below if you face any difficulty solving this.

Comment: We were using JBoss 4.2.0