# How to enable hotswapping of resources for dependency jars inside war with Wildfly and IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, wildfly, war, hotswap

I got a multi module maven-project building a .war and deploying it to Wildfly V14.0.1. The project has depencendies (.jars) bundled into the deployed .war.

While developing I want to reload classes aswell as resourcefiles from every module at runtime.

I setup Intellj with LiveEdit, HotSwapping (war-exploded etc) and everything works fine if I change classes or resources inside the top-level module (war) or classes from one of the dependencies.

The only thing not working is reloading resourcefiles from one of the dependencies. For example: Let's say I got a resource-folder in one of my modules packaged as jar. Inside there is a file called `mytext.txt` with the content "This is a test". If I access the resource inside my code at runtime, I get the text `"This is a test"`. Now if I change the file's content to `"This is a runtime test"`, the output is still `"This is a test"`. Only redeploying will have the changes take effect. The problem with that is, you lose session and need to journey through the application again.

Project Structure looks like this:

```
.war
|_ ui.jar
|_ db.jar
|_ service.jar
```

I found the following answer stating that it is a problem with libs not reloading in wildfly: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55371871/how-to-programmatically-hot-reload-static-resources-like-xhtml-in-wildfly-server)